# Flutter type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am making my flutter firebase app and in it I'm fetching image from list but its giving me this error  `type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String'` on this line in my listTile

```
 leading: Image.network(
                          _provider.dataToFirestore['images'][0]),
```

Now if I do convert it into string by adding .toString like this

```
 leading: Image.network(_provider.dataToFirestore['images']
                              [0]
                          .toString()),
```

my screen comes back and works but  doesn't shows the image cause it's network type not string so how can I resolve this issue.

This is where I'm storing my image

```
List<String> urlList = [];
Map<String, dynamic> dataToFirestore = {};
```

If anyone understand where I'm making issue please help, thanks

Comment: can you print _provider.dataToFirestore['images'][0] or _provider.dataToFirestore['images'][0].toString()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this message mean is `_provider.dataToFirestore['images'][0])` this returning a `List` of `String` not actually a `String`. You may know `List<String>` and `String` are not the same type of data.What I assume in your case  `_provider.dataToFirestore['images'][0][0])` will return a `String` from the `List of String`

Comment: Yeah I understand what you're saying but with this line _provider.dataToFirestore['images'][0][]0) its giving syntax error what's the solution then

Comment: sorry typing mistake it  suppose to be `['images'][0][0])` and I also edited my line

Comment: Swoop fixed thanks man